# In what other areas is MVVMLight helpful after you have your XAML files talking with your ViewModels

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

As I understand it, one of the benefits of using MVVM/MVVMLight is to separate the views from the models so, it is recommended to use a library such as MVVMLight, that's clear enough, in fact, I'm using MVVMLight to help with the mechanism of putting a multi-page together but what I don't fully understand is what other parts of MVVMLight are useful once you have your pages (ViewModels and XAML files) talking to each other.

For instance, the following two options work in the same way, except that in option 2 I'm using `MVVMLight` but what I don't fully understand is what am I gaining by MVVMLight.

what am I gaining by using option `2` instead of option `1`?

Can someone please give me a couple of examples on how MVVMLight could help after you have your XAML files talking with your ViewModels?

### Option 1

**XAML**

```
<Button Content="Button"  Command="{Binding FindPdfFileCommand}"/>
```

**ViewModel .cs**

```
namespace Tool.ViewModel
{
    public class FindrViewModel : ViewModelBase
    { 
        public ICommand FindPdfFileCommand{get;private set;}
        public FindrViewModel(){ FindPdfFileCommand = new RelayCommand(() => FindPdfFile_Click());}

        private void FindPdfFile_Click()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Button clicked");
        }
    }
}
```

### Option 2

**XAML**

```
    xmlns:GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform"
    xmlns:Custom="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"

    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button">
        <Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
            <Custom:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                <GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand x:Name="ClickMeEvent" Command="{Binding FindPdfFileCommand, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </Custom:EventTrigger>
        </Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Button>
```

**ViewModel .cs**

```
namespace Tool.ViewModel
{
    public class FindrViewModel : ViewModelBase
    { 
        public ICommand FindPdfFileCommand{get;private set;}
        public FindrViewModel(){ FindPdfFileCommand = new RelayCommand(() => FindPdfFile_Click());}

        private void FindPdfFile_Click()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Button clicked");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case I suggest to use your 1. solution. In the 1. one you also use MVVMLight: RelayCommand is defined in MVVMLight library, isn't it?

Do not use EventToCommand-trigger if you can simple use a command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As I understand it, one of the benefits of using MVVM/MVVMLight is to separate the views from the models ...

That's the puspose of the pattern itself. MVVM is nothing but a design pattern. You can implement it yourself without using any third-party library such as `MvvmLight` or `Prism` if you want to.

The main benefit of using a library is that it provides you with most things that you will need to develop an MVVM application out of the box. This for example includes a base class that raises implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raises change notifications and an implementation of the `ICommand` interface.

In your example, you are for example using the `ViewModelBase` and `RelayCommand` classes. If you are not using `MvvmLight`, you will have to implement these yourself.

`EventToCommand` is not really useful in this scenario though. It is mainly used when you want to pass the `EventArgs` of the event as a command parameter to the command: http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2014/01/using-the-eventargsconverter-in-mvvm-light-and-why-is-there-no-eventtocommand-in-the-windows-8-1-version/.

You might as well bind to the command property directly here:

```
Command="{Binding FindPdfFileCommand}"/>
```

But you are still using `MvvmLight` types in your view model.

Comment: @ mm8 - Can you please clarify your last statement. Are you saying that even though we are Binding directly when using `Command="{Binding FindPdfFileCommand}"/> ` MVVMLight is still facilitating/helping with binding process?

Comment: No. MvvmLight has nothing to with this binding nor anything else in the XAML.

Answer (score 1):

RelayCommand (and any other [ICommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand(v=vs.110).aspx) implementation) adds another key feature on top of the Execute action - namely the CanExecute property.

This allows you to control when the command can be executed, based on other state of your ViewModel object. Any bound button (or other control with a command property such a menuitem) will be automatically disabled when the command can't be executed. The ViewModel now has indirect control of the user interface, without requiring any direct knowledge of how the command is being used.